# Local Models for shifted symplectic structures

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, symplectic-geometry

I have a problem to get the signs right in the calculation in the proof of Prop 1.21 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3209.pdf on shifted symplectic structures. The authors obtain a ètale local model for the canonical $n$-shifted symplectic structure $\omega$ on the $n$-shifted derived cotangent stack $T^{\ast}X[n]$ of a derived Deligne Mumford stack $X$. So localy $X=Spec(k[x_{1},...,x_{k}])$ with $|x_{i}|\leq 0$ is quasi free and $T^{\ast}X[n] = Spec(k[x_{1},...,x_{k},y_{1},...,y_{k}])=B$ with $|y_{i}| = n-|x_{i}|$.
The symplectic structure is given locally as the element $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^{|y_{i}|}d_{dR}y_{i} \wedge d_{dR}x_{i} \in (Sym^{2}(\Omega_{T^{\ast}X[n]}[1])[n-2])^{0}$.
I am interested in the associated morphism

$\omega^{\#}:T_{T^{\ast}X[n]} =\oplus_{i=1}^{k} B\partial x_{i} \oplus_{i=1}^{k} B \partial y_{i}\rightarrow \Omega_{T^{\ast}X[n]}[n] = \oplus_{i=1}^{k} B d_{dR}x_{i}[n] \oplus_{i=1}^{k} B d_{dR}y_{i}[n] $

It is claimed by the authors that the morphismis given on generators by

$\partial x_{i} \mapsto -(-1)^{|y_{i}|}dy_{i}[n]$ and $ \partial y_{i} \mapsto (-1)^{|x_{i}|}dx_{i}[n]$

Is there an easy way of seeing this? I have tried to reproduce thsi morphism many times, but I never obtained the right signs.

Thank you very much for your help.